# Ubuntu 17.10 guest in Virtualbox 5.2, Xorg driver not working

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 17.10 as a guest in Virtualbox 5.2.8 running on a Windows 7 host.  I'm using Xorg, not Wayland.  This has previously been working correctly, but I rebooted the system a couple of days ago and Xorg is no longer finding the virtualbox display driver, so is falling back to just using regular framebuffer (which means automatic resizing isn't working, and it's only using one of the two configured monitors).

I've attempted to reinstall the guest additions from the CD image, which apparently succeeded, but after rebooting there has been no change.  I do seem to have appropriate kernel modules installed, as `dmesg` indicates they're loading correctly:

```
[    9.311374] vboxguest: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    9.311745] vboxguest: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    9.325936] vgdrvHeartbeatInit: Setting up heartbeat to trigger every 2000 milliseconds
[    9.326122] input: Unspecified device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/input/input7
[    9.327069] vboxguest: misc device minor 55, IRQ 20, I/O port d040, MMIO at 00000000f0000000 (size 0x400000)
[    9.327072] vboxguest: Successfully loaded version 5.2.8 (interface 0x00010004)
[   10.199552] MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
[   10.456176] [drm] VRAM 01800000
[   10.461989] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 2019822 kiB
[   10.461991] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[   10.462001] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[   10.486730] fbcon: vboxdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   10.535460] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
[   10.537908] vboxvideo 0000:00:02.0: fb0: vboxdrmfb frame buffer device
[   10.552475] [drm] Initialized vboxvideo 1.0.0 20130823 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
...
[   14.148062] vboxsf: Successfully loaded version 5.2.8 (interface 0x00010004)
[   17.380413] VBoxService 5.2.8 r121009 (verbosity: 0) linux.amd64 (Feb 26 2018 15:59:51) release log
               00:00:00.000341 main     Log opened 2018-09-15T06:01:13.461172000Z
[   17.380506] 00:00:00.000496 main     OS Product: Linux
[   17.380570] 00:00:00.000563 main     OS Release: 4.13.0-38-generic
[   17.380640] 00:00:00.000627 main     OS Version: #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018
[   17.380715] 00:00:00.000696 main     Executable: /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.2.8/sbin/VBoxService
               00:00:00.000697 main     Process ID: 538
               00:00:00.000698 main     Package type: LINUX_64BITS_GENERIC
[   17.382905] 00:00:00.002833 main     5.2.8 r121009 started. Verbose level = 0
[   17.395666] 00:00:00.015607 automount vbsvcAutoMountWorker: Shared folder 'E_DRIVE' was mounted to '/media/sf_E_DRIVE'
```

However, Xorg is complaining about a missing driver when I start it:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.5
Release Date: 2017-10-12
[   740.609] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   740.609] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   740.610] Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu17 4.13.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018 x86_64
[   740.610] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/@/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic root=UUID=b01e5b7f-6cdc-44b6-b718-06a7ecf06177 ro rootflags=subvol=@ splash quiet
[   740.610] Build Date: 15 October 2017  05:51:19PM
[   740.610] xorg-server 2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   740.610] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   740.610]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   740.610] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
...
[   740.696] (==) Matched vboxvideo as autoconfigured driver 0
[   740.696] (==) Matched vboxvideo as autoconfigured driver 1
[   740.696] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[   740.696] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[   740.696] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[   740.697] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   740.697] (II) LoadModule: "vboxvideo"
[   740.698] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vboxvideo
[   740.698] (II) UnloadModule: "vboxvideo"
[   740.698] (II) Unloading vboxvideo
[   740.698] (EE) Failed to load module "vboxvideo" (module does not exist, 0)
```

Looking in `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers`, there is indeed no `vboxvideo` driver module installed, which is odd because it must have been there last time I restarted, because it was all working fine.

Where is this driver supposed to come from?  Does the virtualbox guest additions installation script not install it?  Or do I need to install it from somewhere else (note that I'm using Virtualbox 5.2, while the virtualbox version used by Ubuntu is 5.1, so the guest additions provided by Ubuntu doesn't work with this host and using it is therefore not an option)?